# Raphaël - transformPath() to return lines instead of curves

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Is it possible to get Raphael.transformPath() to return a path made of lines instead of a path made of curves?

```
                var path = "M10,20L30,40";
                var trans = "t100,100s2,2";
                var trpath = Raphael.transformPath(path, trans);
                console.log('trpath: ' + trpath);
```

will output:

```
trpath: M100,110C100,110,140,150,140,150
```

I need this path with only straight lines!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird, not sure why Raphael chooses to do this. But not too hard to get around:

If you consult [the source](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.core.js#L2168) for the .transformPath() method, you'll see that it is a composite of two other utility methods:

```
transformPath = R.transformPath = function (path, transform) {
    return mapPath(path, toMatrix(path, transform));
}
```

Pretty straight-forward: .toMatrix() parses that transform string into a matrix, and mapPath applies that matrix to the path string.

For some reason, mapPath includes a call to the [.path2curve() method](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.path2curve), which is why you're having trouble. So we need to [grab the source](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.core.js#L294) for that method and modify it:

```
var mapPathStraight = function (path, matrix) {
    if (!matrix) {
        return path;
    }
    var x, y, i, j, ii, jj, pathi;
    //replace following line with .parsePathString(), which also parses path string into an array without adding curves
    //path = path2curve(path);
    path = Raphael.parsePathString(path);
    for (i = 0, ii = path.length; i < ii; i++) {
        pathi = path[i];
        for (j = 1, jj = pathi.length; j < jj; j += 2) {
            x = matrix.x(pathi[j], pathi[j + 1]);
            y = matrix.y(pathi[j], pathi[j + 1]);
            pathi[j] = x;
            pathi[j + 1] = y;
        }
    }
    return path;
};
```

Now we can achieve a straight line like so:

```
var trpath = mapPathStraight(path, Raphael.toMatrix(path, trans));
```

Which gives me an output of:

```
trpath: M100,110L140,150
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pattj/1/)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you so much for this, works really well!

Comment: Found this very useful, however .path2curve() method turns out to be needed in some cases. In particular try "M100,100A100,100,0,1,0,101,100" and you'll get a NaN's in the result and a nasty error when you try and render.